# proof of differentiation with integrals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable. Define, for $x \in [a,b]$,
$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$ and $G(x) = \int_a^x F(t)dt$.

How do I prove that $G$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$?

I was trying to prove this for a while now, and still did not come with a satisfying proof.
I know that there is theorem that tells me that $F$ is continuous, but I am not sure how this helps. Can anyone help me with this proof? Thank you!

Comment: Use fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)$ integrable $\Rightarrow$ $F(x)$ continuous $\Rightarrow$ $G(x)$ differentiable

For the last step, use the definition of derivative
$$
\lim_{x->x_0} \frac{G(x)-G(x_0)}{x-x_0} = \left\{
\begin{aligned}
& F(x_0+) \text{  when }  x>x_0\\
& F(x_0-) \text{  when }  x<x_0
\end{aligned}\right. 
$$

Since $F(x)$ is continuous, so $F(x_0+)=F(x_0-)=F(x_0)$
So $G(x)$ differentiable